# Select Form - Link two tables in a third table

Tags: php, mysql, forms, join, select

It's my first time here so please, be gentle...

My name is Maxime and I'm trying to learn PHP for few weeks now. I searched a lot on stack and Internet but I didn't find the solution, so I'm sorry if this is "basic" or if I don't explain very well. I'm looking for help!

---

---

This week, I'm trying something :
I have 2 tables :

**BARLIST**

```
|-----------+--------+----------+-----+---------|
|   barId   | barName| Adresse  | lat | long    |
|-----------+--------+----------+---------------|
|     1     |   Mike |50 street | 50  |  1.5    |
|     2     |   John |51 street | 30  |  45     |
|     3     |   Beth |52 street | 26  |  87     |
|-----------+--------+----------+---------------|
```

**BEERLIST**

```
|--------+----------+----------|
| beerId | beerName | typeBeer |
|--------+----------+----------|
|   1    |   Leffe  | blond    |
|   2    |   Affli  | brune    |
|   3    |   Affli  | blanche  |
|--------+----------+----------|
```

**BARBEER - The linking table I would like**

```
|--------+----------+----------|
| Id     | beerId   | barId    |
|--------+----------+----------|
|   1    |   1      | 1        |
|   2    |   2      | 1        |
|   3    |   3      | 2        |
|--------+----------+----------|
```

The idea is to let the user choose a bar and a beer from the tables through a select form, to add them into the third table *barbeer*. So I've trying few things and recently here what I have.

**Form with select content**

```php
<form method="post" action="">
            <label class="first-column ">Choose a bar</label><div class="second-column">
                <select name="test">
                    <option>Select</option>
                    <?php

                    $sqli = "SELECT * FROM barList";
                    $result = mysqli_query($con, $sqli);
                    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc(@$result)) {
                        ?>
                        <option value="<?php echo $row['barId'];?>"><?php echo $row['barName'];?></option>';
                        <?php
                    }


                    ?>
                </select>

                <label class="first-column ">Choose a beer</label><div class="second-column">
                    <select name="test1">
                        <option>Select</option>
                        <?php

                        $sqli = "SELECT * FROM beerList";
                        $result = mysqli_query($con, $sqli);
                        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc(@$result)) {
                            # code...?>
                        <option value="<?php echo $row['beerId'];?>"><?php echo $row['beerName'];?></option>';
                      <?php
                        }


                        ?>
                    </select>
            <input type="submit" name="submit_4" value="Submit" />
```

It works great and I can see on my form the name of the beer and the bar.
But now I would like to add the selection of the user into a third table, so I tried this :

```php
if(isset($_POST['submit_4'])){
    if(empty($errors)){
        try
        {
            $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=whereismybeer;charset=utf8', 'root', '');
        }
        catch(Exception $e)
        {
            die('Erreur : '.$e->getMessage());
        }
        echo $_POST['test'];
        echo $_POST['test1'];
        
        $req= $pdo-> prepare("INSERT INTO barbeer JOIN barList, ON barbeer.barId = ? JOIN beerList, ON barbeer.beerId = ?");
        $req->execute([$_POST['test'], $_POST['test']]);
        
        die ('Yeah, It worked!');

    }}
```

Also I tried with a variable like this

```php
$var = $_POST['test];
INSERT INTO [...] barbeer.barID = $var;
```

I had no error messages, just the "Yeah, It worked!" but nothing on the barbeer table... So I'm stuck.
Could you help me to find a solution, ideas or anything useful?

Thank you very much for the answer and the help!

***EDIT :** In another page, in the future, the idea will be to ask "where can I drink this beer?", and the website to show the list of the bar where I could drink this beer! That's why I thought a Joint would be necessary.*

**EDIT 2 :** Ok, so my understanding of the JOIN function was wrong. I don't need to call it now. I just need to put the beerID and the barID into the third table with a classic INSERT.

```php
INSERT INTO barbiere (barName, biereName) VALUES (?, ?);
```

Comment: There's no need for any JOINs here is there?

Comment: _Don’t_ output “yeah, it worked”, if you did not actually _check_ whether what you tried to do before _actually_ worked.

Comment: Hi, in another page, in the future, the idea will be to ask "where can I drink this beer?", and the website to show the list of the bar where I could drink this beer! So I thought a JOIN would be necessary  ! (Sorry I forgot to mention it!).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to use join. You have the values of beerId, barId from the form. So just do a normal insert.

The statement should be.

```
INSERT INTO barbeer (beerId, barId) VALUES (?, ?);
```

Comment: Oh ok, like this It worked. So If in another page I want to know which bar have this kind of beer, I will just have to compare the barId from the table barbeer and barList, that's right? No need of join at all?

Comment: You can get the barIds associated with the beerId from barbeer table. To get the information of that bar you need to join with bar table, or you could make two queries, one to get the barIds and another to get information of those bars with these barIds. Obviously, using join is efficient.

Comment: ok, the use of join will be on the other page ! It was my understanding of the join that was wrong. Thank you very much!